# Stencil, Leaflet, unit testing component, gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'deviceXDPI' of undefined

Tags: unit-testing, leaflet, jestjs, jsdom, stenciljs

So we are developing a Stenciljs component which wraps leaflet map and adds some additional functionality.

Now obviously we don't want or need to test Leaflet, but instead, just the parts in our wrapper components.

So, using the test examples, we create our tests,

```
import { LeMap } from "./le-map";

describe("Map component tests", () => {
    it("Should build the map component", async () => {
        const map = new LeMap();
        expect(map).not.toBeNull();
    });     
});
```

try and load the components and test the public functions, but we get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'deviceXDPI' of undefined

> 1 | import {Component, Element, Listen, Method, Prop, Watch} from 
'@stencil/core';
> 2 | import L from 'leaflet';
    | ^
  3 |
  4 | @Component({
  5 |       shadow: false,
```

We believe this message is because the test is trying to render leaflet, and because it's not a true browser, it can't detect a view so throwing this error, so we've tried to mock leaflet in the tests, but still get the same problem.

We're tried to mock the leaflet module by using jest mocking

```
jest.genMockFromModule('leaflet');
```

but this made no diffrence

Only idea I've had is to separate the logic from the components, but that feels wrong, as we'd just be doing this for purpose of testing.

Versions in use are: leaflet: 1.3.4, @stencil: 0.15.2, jest: 23.4.2

Any other suggestions?

Further investigation with, thanks to @skyboyer 's suggestions, leads me to this line of the leaflet core browser.js file

leads me to this line of the leaflet core browser.js file

```
export var retina = (window.devicePixelRatio || (window.screen.deviceXDPI/window.screen.logicalXDPI)) > 1;
```

But I'm unable to mock the screen property of window as I get the following error

```
[ts] Cannot assign to 'screen' because it is a constant or a read-only property,
```

so I try the following.

```
const screen =  {
    deviceXDPI:0,
    logicalXDPI:0
}

Object.defineProperty(window, 'screen', screen);
Object.defineProperty(window, 'devicePixelRatio', 0);
```

Same error, completely ignores this, so I try over riding the export.

```
jest.spyOn(L.Browser,'retina').mockImplementation(() => false);
```

No joy either, so tried

```
L.Browser.retina = jest.fn(() => false);
```

but get it tells me it's a constant and can't be changed (yet the implication stats var so ¯_(ツ)_/¯ )

Anything else I can try?

Further update, 
I've managed to mock the window, but this sadly doesn't solve it.

```
const screenMock = {            
    deviceXDPI: 0,
    logicalXDPI: 0          
}

const windowMock = {
    value: {
        'devicePixelRatio': 0,
        'screen': screenMock
    }
}
Object.defineProperty(global, 'window', windowMock);
```

If I console log this, I get the right properties but as soon as I test the instantiation of the component it fails with

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'deviceXDPI' of undefined
```

Reading around it seems Leaflet doesn't check for a DOM and just tries to render anyway, I can't see anyway around this, I saw a leaflet-headless package, but I don't know how I could swap them out just for testing.

Think I will need to look at another strategy for testing, probably protractor.

Comment: you may start from mocking this method: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom
but I'm not sure how many methods you need to mock to run tests

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, not fully tested yet, but the tests pass.
I did it by creating a

```
__mocks__
```

directory at the same level as the node_modules directory.
created a file called leaflet.js in it. It's a simple file it just contains.

```
'use strict';

const leaflet = jest.fn();

module.exports = leaflet;
```

then in my test file (le-map.spec.ts) I just added

```
jest.mock('leaflet')
```

before the imports

and now my test passes.

I tried doing this in the test itself but that just gave me the same error, it must be something in the loading sequence which means it has to be manually mocked beforehand.

Hope this helps others, it's been driving me mad for weeks.